# Using field other than id for rails routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm wanting to use a short url similar to a short url from bit.ly. Currently i have `resources :clips` instead of accessing clips/:id in my route i want to access it from my url_hash field on my Clips model. Am I going to have to manually list the routes to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the slugged gem:

https://github.com/Sutto/slugged

or (more popular):, friendly_id

https://github.com/norman/friendly_id